# read an array in fortran using gfortran compiler

Tags: arrays, gfortran

I would like to read a data array in a fortran code with this line: 
read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, (datbinsa(ibin), & ibin= 1, nbins), (datbinsb(ibin), ibin= 1, nbins)

I am compiling with gfortran. Unfortunately, this error message appears: 
read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, (datbinsa(ibin), & 1 Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)

I can read the lines if I put only: 
read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, datbinsa(ibin) But I would like to read the whole array! 
How can I read an array when usin ggfortran as compiler? 
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Please format your code as code.  See the icons above the text edit box ?  The one which looks like `{}` is the one you need.